# Does Multiprocessing process have to be terminated at the end of function called?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Would it be a good practice to include `proc.terminate()` and `proc.join()` at the very end of the function to make sure the `multiprocessing` process is closed/shut down/terminated after it is done with its job (the end of function it ran has been reached)?

From a testing I've made it seems every `multiprocessing` process terminates itself without any need to implicitly terminating it with `proc.terminate()`. But I still would like to make sure terminating the process at the end of the function is not necessary.

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def myFunct(arg):
    proc=mp.current_process()
    print 'starting:', proc.name, proc.pid,'...\n'
    for i in range(110):
        for n in range(500000):
            pass
    print '\t ...', proc.name, proc.pid, 'completed\n'

    print 'Is proc alive:', proc.is_alive()
    proc.terminate()
    print 'TERMINATED:', proc.is_alive()
    proc.join()
    print 'JOINED:', proc.is_alive()


pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
pool.map_async( myFunct, [1,2,3])
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not necessary. In fact, it's explicitly discouraged in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate):

> Note that the start(), join(), is_alive(), terminate() and exitcode
>   methods **should only be called by the process that created the process
>   object**.

You shouldn't be calling `terminate` and `join` inside your worker function. When you use a `multiprocessing.pool` the processes in the pool will stay open

1. As long as you haven't called `pool.close()`
2. As long as the process is doing work.

In your case, you're calling `pool.close` right after making your `map_async` call, so the processes in the pool will shutdown as soon as they're done processing. The `pool.join` call will ensure your program waits until that happens to shutdown.

Comment: Interesting... would you please post an example how would it be possible to terminate() process from the process that created the process object... Please edit my example code to illustrate it.

Comment: Aside from it I would like to know how to 'return' from `myFunct()` if there is an error, exception and etc. Please post some example on how to exit myFunct() if there is an exception. Because simple `return` used inside of myFunct() scope doesn't terminate the Process...

Comment: @Sputnix The workers in process pools aren't meant to terminate themselves. All the processes in the pool will remain open until `pool.close()` is called in the main process. Once `pool.close` has been called, the worker process will terminate as soon as `myFunc` returns, assuming there are no outstanding tasks remaining in the pool's queue.

Comment: Is there a way to get the processes PIDs or Process Objects (processes instances) using one of the `pool` methods? It seems I am loosing control over the PROCESSes after they started... It would be great if there are some way to keep a track what the Process is doing from outside of the PROCESS itself.

Comment: @Sputnix You can get a list of all the `multiprocessing.Process` objects in the pool using `pool._pool`. I'd be careful about messing with it though; it's meant to be a private variable, so I'm not sure what kind of strange behavior you'll see if you mess with the processes in the pool directly.

Comment: If used `pool.join()` is locking up the GUI. Would it be safe to use `pool.close()` without finishing it with `pool.join()`?

Comment: Would it be proper to use: `pool=mp.Pool(2);  pool.map_async(myFunc,[1,2,3]);  pool.close()`          instead of using `pool=mp.Pool(2);  pool.map_async(myFunc,[1,2,3]);  pool.close()   ;   pool.join()` (pool.join() at the end is omitted.

Comment: If you've got a GUI running, then you don't need to call `pool.join()`. You only need to use `join` if you actually want to wait around for the pool to finish processing the tasks if you've given before doing any other work in your program. Just using `pool.close()` to signal that no more tasks will be given to the pool is fine.